# Rounded window corners on GNOME 3.36?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, customization

---

The title says it all but...

I want to make ALL 4 corners of ALL windows be rounded, **Firefox included**, just like on the new *GNOME 40*.

I'm **not** a programmer of any sort, I'm actually a visual designer & musician, so I don't know how to do that by myself.

Any way how I can do this?

*Also, yes I did in fact check all other questions relating to this, none of them are really useful to my case.*

System: *Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Ubuntu Studio Installer, GNOME Shell 3.36, X11.*

Comment: GNOME is designed to be "distraction-free", so there are not many customization options. If you want this much fine-tuned control over the UI, use a different DE like KDE which is designed to be highly customizable

Comment: @Nmath I've tried using KDE (Manjaro KDE Plasma to be exact) for some time before, didn't like it alot, too complex for me & my favorite themes are not supported there.

Comment: Well I don't know what to tell you because any themes for GNOME are a decade old and probably only work for GTK2 and are typically extremely buggy because GNOME devs don't care about your themes and actually [beg/warn you not to do it](https://stopthemingmy.app/).  Are you sure that your problems were with KDE and not Manjaro, which is based on Arch which is well known for being "complicated"?  If you insist on making GNOME look like how you want it, you're going to have a bad time. If Kubuntu doesn't work, try another flavor. You can "Try Ubuntu" in a live session without installing

Comment: The way that GNOME is designed, if you don't like how the UI looks, don't use it. This should be obvious by the fact that you are not allowed to change practically anything without having to install third party software to crack the UI.  And even then, the options are still extremely limited.  There are dozens of other desktop environments that permit and encourage you customize, but trying to heavily customize GNOME is a fool's errand.  One of the benefits of using Linux/Ubuntu is that you get to choose the software you want. Don't choose software that doesn't have the features you want/need

Comment: After some months, I managed to install KDE Plasma here on Ubuntu(Using Kubuntu reposites), way better customization I might say.